# Flower snarks are of Class II

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to show that [flower snarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_snark) are indeed snarks (other than $F_3$), meaning that they are of Class II from Vizing's theorem. That is to say, I want to show that the chromatic index of every flower snark is 4. I have been trying this for a while and every time it just turns into ridiculous case analysis in one way or another.

I have proven the statement by working it all out, but I was just wondering if there is a nice, elegant, more theoretic way of doing this. My one thought was to use Blanusa's Lemma about parity of the number of edges in an edge cut, but I cannot make much progress with this.

I have also observed that three colors are needed to color the outer cycle even though it is an odd cycle, because of the way the "petals" connect. Perhaps there is a way to show it cannot connect well with the 3-edge-coloring of the inner cycle?

Thank you for any advice you can give.